# Writing long code as nested list comprehension

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops

I am writing a code IN Python to compute the discrete Laplacian as a sparse matrix in 2D. The code is as follows:

```
def discretizeLaplacian(N, step):
    NN = N**2
    dxx = (float) (1/((step)**2))
    i_loc, j_loc, vals = np.array([]), np.array([]), np.array([])
    for i in range(1, N-1):
        for j in range(1, N-1):      
            iv0 = j*N + i
            iv1 = (j - 1)*N + i
            iv2 = (j + 1)*N + i
            iv3 = j*N + i - 1
            iv4 = j*N + i + 1
            i_loc = np.concatenate((i_loc,[iv0, iv0, iv0, iv0, iv0]))
            j_loc = np.concatenate((j_loc,[iv0, iv1, iv2, iv3, iv4]))
            vals = np.concatenate((vals,dxx*np.array([-4, 1, 1, 1, 1])))
    sparseMatrix = csc_matrix((vals, (i_loc, j_loc)), shape = (NN, NN))
    return sparseMatrix
```

The for loop runs much longer compared to Matlab. I am wondering if I can write it as nested list comprehension to make it faster.

Comment: A list comprehension is just syntactic sugar to a normal loop. This shouldn't improve efficiency.

Comment: Well, there are other posts saying that list comprehension in Python is much faster than normal loop as the way it accesses the memory.

Comment: @mozway is correct. It will not run faster using a list comprehension. At one time it was the case. Newer versions of Python will optimize your code, and regular loops will run the same as one written with a list comprehension.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to make this code run faster?

Comment: Would https://stackoverflow.com/a/66080877/51685 work for you?

Comment: Without access to the corresponding Matlab code it's really hard to speculate what it's doing differently, but the typical answer is to use vectorized operations _instead of_ loops.

Comment: The Matlab code is exactly the same as I wrote above.

Comment: @mozway It *theoretically* shouldn't, but it *actually does improve efficiency*. See [this code](https://godbolt.org/z/5nofrrPTs) on GoldBolt. The comprehension list generate a significantly more efficient bytecode. In practice, the comprehension list version is more than 2 times faster that the plain loop on my machine with the last version of CPython.

Comment: @JérômeRichard  A good chunk of that is repeated lookups of `lst.append`, which can be easily refactored by setting `f = lst.append` before the loop. The rest of the speed up is due to using the `LIST_APPEND` byte code instead of having to actually call a list method. So in some extremely narrow situations, the list comprehension can be faster, but real code usually has more complex cases that wash out that speed-up.

Comment: I guess `j*N + I` is a typing mistake. Shouldn't it be `j*N + i`?

Comment: @chepner Indeed, but `LIST_APPEND` alone make the code 50% faster in this case. This is sad to have to manually write `f = lst.append` (less readable IMHO) to get good performance. I don't fully agree with the "*extremely* narrow situations" since comprehension lists are generally used in simple cases (where the operation tends to be not very expensive). The use-case of the OP is not so simple though.

Comment: It's also a trivial sample that's 4-10x slower than `list(range(100))`.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Yes, it was a mistake.

Comment: @chepner How can use LIST_APPEND?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slow performance comes from the **bad complexity** of the algorithm. Indeed, the complexity of the original code is `O(N**4)`! This is due to **`np.concatenate` which creates a new array** by copying the old one and adding a few items at the end of the new one. This means that `O(N**2)` copies of 3 growing arrays are performed. In general, you should avoid `np.concatenate` in a loop to make a growing array. You should use Python lists in that case.

Note that you can use `np.tile` to repeat values of an array and pre-compute the constant `dxx * np.array([-4, 1, 1, 1, 1])`.

Here is the corrected code:

```py
def discretizeLaplacian(N, step):
    NN = N**2
    dxx = (float) (1/((step)**2))
    tmp = dxx * np.array([-4, 1, 1, 1, 1])
    i_loc, j_loc = [], []
    for i in range(1, N-1):
        for j in range(1, N-1):   
            iv0 = j*N + I
            iv1 = (j - 1)*N + i
            iv2 = (j + 1)*N + i
            iv3 = j*N + i - 1
            iv4 = j*N + i + 1
            i_loc.extend([iv0, iv0, iv0, iv0, iv0])
            j_loc.extend([iv0, iv1, iv2, iv3, iv4])
    i_loc = np.array(i_loc, dtype=np.float64)
    j_loc = np.array(j_loc, dtype=np.float64)
    vals = np.tile(tmp, (N-2)**2)
    sparseMatrix = csc_matrix((vals, (i_loc, j_loc)), shape = (NN, NN))
    return sparseMatrix
```

Here are performance results on my machine with N=200:

```
Original code:   22.510 s
Corrected code:   0.068 s
```

While you can use list comprehensions to set `i_loc` with `[j*N+I for i in range(1, N-1) for j in range(1, N-1)]`, it is not easy for `j_loc` due to the multiple items to append. You can build a list of list/tuple and then flatten it, but it makes the code less readable and not faster.

If this is not fast enough, you can use Numpy **vectorized functions** (such as `np.meshgrid`, `np.arange`, and basic math operations) to build `i_loc` and `j_loc`. Please consider reading the [Numpy tutorials](https://numpy.org/learn/) about that. Python loops are generally very slow since Python codes are generally *interpreted*. Matlab uses internally a [**just-in-time compiler**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) (JIT) to execute such a loop-based code quickly. You can use **Numba** or **Cython** to do the same thing in Python.

Comment: Wow, this is great!