Python Equivalent for Computing Discrete Laplacian, Comparable to Matlab's "del2"
In Matlab, the "del2" function is used for computing the discrete Laplacian. I'm searching for a comparable function or method in Python to perform the same task.
Could anyone suggest an equivalent function or approach in Python to compute the discrete Laplacian? Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
import deepxde

def pde_1D(x, y):
    V, W = y[:, 0:1], y[:, 1:2]
    dv_dt = dde.grad.jacobian(y, x, i=0, j=1)
    dv_dxx = dde.grad.hessian(y, x, component=0, i=0, j=0)
    dw_dt = dde.grad.jacobian(y, x, i=1, j=1)
    ## Coupled PDE+ODE Equations
    eq_a = dv_dt -  D*dv_dxx + k*V*(V-a)*(V-1) +W*V
    eq_b = dw_dt -  (epsilon + (mu_1*W)/(mu_2+V))*(-W -k*V*(V-b-1))
    return [eq_a, eq_b]


More discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692196/discrete-laplacian-del2-equivalent-in-python

Scipy has a scipy.stats.dlaplace which can be used to compute the dlaplace probability mass function:
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import dlaplace
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
a = 0.8
mean, var, skew, kurt = dlaplace.stats(a, moments='mvsk')
x = np.arange(dlaplace.ppf(0.01, a),
              dlaplace.ppf(0.99, a))
ax.plot(x, dlaplace.pmf(x, a), 'bo', ms=8, label='dlaplace pmf')
ax.vlines(x, 0, dlaplace.pmf(x, a), colors='b', lw=5, alpha=0.5)

